# How to make StackLayout collapse when currentIndex === -1?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

The following code just do a simple thing: change the `currentIndex` of `StackLayout` to `-1` when clicked. But I want to let the height of `StackLayout` to be `0` when `currentIndex` is `-1`.

```
Window {
    id: window
    width: 400
    height: 400
    visible: true
    color: "#181818"
    MouseArea {
        id: ma
        anchors.fill: parent
        hoverEnabled: true
        onClicked: lay.currentIndex = -1
    }

    StackLayout {
        id: lay
        anchors.top: parent.top
        Rectangle {
            width: 300
            height: 100
            color: "white"
        }
    }
    Rectangle {
        anchors.top: lay.bottom
        width: 200
        height: 100
        color: "red"
    }
}
```

I've tried Binding like

```
Binding {
    when: lay.currentIndex === -1
    lay.height: 0
}
```

But this won't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a normal declarative binding:
`height: currentIndex === -1 ? 0 : implicitHeight`

You might want to change it to
`visible: currentIndex !== -1` and use a ColumnLayout as the parent to automatically position the Rectangle too.

Answer (score 0):

You are able to listen the built-in `onCurrentIndexChanged` signal

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12

Window {
    id: window
    width: 400
    height: 400
    visible: true
    color: "#181818"
    MouseArea {
        id: ma
        anchors.fill: parent
        hoverEnabled: true
        onClicked:lay.currentIndex = -1
    }

    StackLayout {
        id: lay
        anchors.top: parent.top
        Rectangle {
            width: 300
            height: 100
            color: "white"
        }
        onCurrentIndexChanged: {
            if (lay.curentIndex === -1)
                lay.height = 0
        }
    }
    Rectangle {
        anchors.top: lay.bottom
        width: 200
        height: 100
        color: "red"
    }
}
```

Just tested on Qt 5.12.8

Comment: It might not be the best solution, because when I rechange `currentIndex` to other value, the height will not restore.

Comment: You can use trenary operator 
```onCurrentIndexChanged: { lay.height = lay.currentIndex === -1 ? 0 : 100 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that I can achieve my goal by setting `height: currentIndex === -1 ? 0 : undefined` simply. :)